# IOS Core data fetch-request - sorting

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am using a background thread to fetch limited number of records sorted with date.

Everything works well until I delete a record in the UI thread (tableview ).

```
//this is done in the background thread
NSFetchRequest *frequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" 
                                            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[frequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:@"date"     
                                    ascending:NO];

NSArray *descriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[frequest setSortDescriptors:descriptors];

[frequest setFetchOffset:fetchOffset];    
[frequest setFetchLimit:20];

[frequest setResultType:NSManagedObjectIDResultType];

 NSError *fetchError;
 NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:frequest 
                                                                               error:&fetchError] mutableCopy];
```

The background thread is registered for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and performs the following selector

```
//this is done in the background thread
-(void) didSavePersistenceStore:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

The problem: After deleting a record, subsequent fetch results are not sorted with date anymore.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Your code is correct. IMHO, the error must lie elsewhere.

Comment: That notification will come through on the main thread and cause `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` to be run on the main thread, which is not the correct thread. No idea if this is causing the issue but it sure does sound like some subtle bugs could occur

Comment: The target for mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification is the ManagedObjectContext associated with the background thread. Will it matter which thread calls the message in this case?

Comment: Yup the notification will occur on the thread that posted it

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you do not use the managedObjectContext from the wrong thread.  You can call performBlock to do it in the proper context.

Second, the fetch descriptor you use for the fetch does not persist.  So, unless you keep fetching with the same sorting criteria, you won't get it that way.

If you want that behavior, use a fetch results controller.  It will maintain your desired view into the database.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation:

`If you set the value to NSManagedObjectIDResultType, this will demote any sort orderings to “best efforts” hints if you do not include the property values in the request.`

You need to write all changes to persistent store or set includesPendingChanges to NO.